# jQuery if statement to find and replace certain header text is replacing all headers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to identify a certain h4 tag that contains certain text and class (it unfortunately does not have an id) and then replace that text. I have the following if statement, but when an h4 matches true for this if statement, it replaces all h4 tags on the page instead of just the one that rang true.

My challenge is that I can only implement this via global jQuery. Is that my downfall?

```
if ($("H4:contains('Topic')") && $('H4').hasClass('boxHeaderTitle')) {
    $('h4').text('Posts');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` expression is a bit odd. The expression will always evaluate to `true` if both of the below are true:

- there is at least one `h4` that contains the text `Topic`. Because in that case, `$("H4:contains('Topic')")` will return a truthy value.
- there is at least one `h4` that has the class `boxHeaderTitle` assigned to it. Because in that case, `$('H4').hasClass('boxHeaderTitle')` will return a truthy value.

The catch is that in the body of `if`, you're setting the text of all the `h4`s to `Posts`.

The correct approach may be:

```
var heading = $("H4:contains('Topic')");

if ( heading.hasClass('boxHeaderTitle')) {
    heading.text('Posts');
}
```

I assume that you want to change the text of an `h4` which contains `Topic` and also has the class `boxHeaderTitle`. Alternatively, you can altogether try a different approach:

```
$("H4.boxHeaderTitle:contains('Topic')").text('Posts');
```

The above works for multiple such tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($("H4:contains('Topic')") && $('H4').hasClass('boxHeaderTitle')) {
$(this).html('Posts');
}
```

or

```
$("H4.boxHeaderTitle:contains('Topic')").each(function(){
$(this).html('Posts');
});
```

Comment: My bad, it should be `$(this).html('Posts');`